# WSO2 iterate calling endpoint until correct response

Tags: wso2, esb

I'm working with wso2 ESB 4.8.1

My complete functionality is:

1. Step one:
   I make a call to a service that respond me with a processId (Asynchcronous)

   The service make the work asociated to that processId
2. Step two:
   I have to iterate calling the service with the processId Until a response that indicate me that process has finished and return me the result

I'm having problems with step two implementation.

Comment: can you show some code here?

Comment: what are the problems you have?

Comment: Hello, My main problem is that i'm new working with wso2 and I don't now how to implement a while loop calling and endpoint until the endpoind response contains a concrete value. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can store the response with the process id into a Message Store.

You define a Message Processor (a scheduled message forwarding processor) that consume messages from this store and send them into a proxy service (defined inside the same ESB)

In this proxy service :

- you call your service with the process id
- you analyse it's response in this proxy outSequence and decide to return it if it's OK (so, the message processor will execute the reply.sequence and delete the message from the store) or return an error if not (the message processor will execute the fault.sequence and let the message in the store so, it will retry it the next time)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you very much I'll try your solution.

I have make some advances with a secuence that check if the processId has finished and if not the secuence call it own (recursion), I'm testing this alternative, I put the code (some thinks are hardcode but the important is the idea)

```
  <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test2">
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="***** IN" value="Estoy en el GET /recursivetest1/test2"></property>
           </log>
         <call>
            <endpoint name="uploadServlet">
               <!-- this is the request that return the processId -->
               <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:1234/ProyectoWebMultipartForm/UploadServlet?fase=escaneo"></http>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log>
            <property name="data_id" expression="json-eval($.data_id)"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="escaneo" expression="json-eval($.data_id)"></property>
         <sequence key="iterate_calls2"></sequence>
         <send></send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>

      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>


/////////////////

<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="iterate_calls2" trace="disable">

   <call>
      <!-- this is the request that check if the processId has finished-->
      <endpoint name="uploadServlet">
         <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:1234/ProyectoWebMultipartForm/UploadServlet?fase=chequeo"></http>
      </endpoint>
   </call>

   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="resultado" expression="json-eval($.scan_results.scan_all_result_a)"></property>
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('resultado')" regex="Clean">
      <then>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="No hay virus"></property>
         </log>
      </then>
      <else>

         <property name="mensaje" expression="json-eval($.mensaje)"></property>
         <filter source="get-property('mensaje')" regex="Escaneo sin finalizar">
            <then>
               <!-- the processId has not finished, I call again to the sequence, recursion-->
               <log level="full">
                  <property name="MESSAGE" value="El escaneo no ha finalizado antes del sleep"></property>
               </log>
               <script language="js">
                  <![CDATA[java.lang.Thread.sleep(200);]]></script>
                  <log level="full">
                     <property name="MESSAGE" value="El escaneo no ha finalizado despues del sleep"></property>
                  </log>
                  <sequence key="iterate_calls2"></sequence>
               </then>
               <else>
                  <!-- the processId has finished, I have end-->
                  <log level="full">
                     <property name="MESSAGE" value="No hay virus"></property>
                  </log>
               </else>
            </filter>
         </else>
      </filter>
   </sequence>
```